# loop input request until valid number accepted

Tags: c#, loops, request

This code is simply throw exception, because short sNum is assigned big range value of int num, and conversion fail. Any way.
I want to loop request until valid rang of short is entered.

```
    static void Main()
    {
        int num = 40000;
        short sNum = 0;
        try
        {
            sNum = Convert.ToInt16(num);

        }
        catch (OverflowException ex)
        {
            // Request for input until no exception thrown.
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            sNum = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("output is {0}",sNum);
                        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: lookup the `while` loop.

Comment: what do you mean by "loop request" ? and short entered how? by the user?

Comment: Use TryParse (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hh1awhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) istead of the exception handler and a while loop (http://www.dotnetperls.com/while).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is you are throwing an exception when the conversion fails inside your `catch` block.  The `catch` block technically is outside of the `try` block, so it will not get caught by the same `catch` as you seem to think.  This is not really behaving as a loop as you appear to hope it will.

Exceptions are not generally considered the best method for normal (non-exceptional) events in your code.  The `TryParse` method and a loop would be much better in this case.

```
static void Main()
{
    string input = //get your user input;
    short sNum = 0;

    while(!short.TryParse(input,out sNum))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input invalid, please try again");
        input = //get your user input;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("output is {0}",sNum);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
short sNum;
string input;

do
{
    input = Console.ReadLine();
} while (!Int16.TryParse(input, out sNum))

Console.WriteLine("output is {0}", sNum);
```